# Reload parent page with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code that runs when a page is closed.

```
$(window).unload(function () {
        window.opener.location.reload();        
});
```

Is there a way to pass a paramenter to the page that calls this closed page ?

Comment: are you in a popup or in an iframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javascript variable window.parent should let you access to any parameters of the parent of the popup.

```
window.parent.reload();
```

from inside the popup should work.

As for the parameter

```
window.parent.variableName = 'Hello World!';
```

will create a variable name variableName in your parent.

So inside the parent, you will be able to do

```
alert(variableName);
```

and have an alert with the content 'Hello World!';

Comment: what kind of parameter? a variable that will be used by the parent, or a option in the url?

Comment: variable that will be used by the parent

Comment: @Hipny when the page is reloaded the `window.parent.variablename` will be cleared.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot you are assuming that he will not use the variable before the the reload and still need it after.

Comment: assignment call and reload call from child window will not give parent window to use it. only if assignment is made using some function call, it can be used before reload call.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot He may trigger and event between the moment the variable is assigned and the moment of the reload, which will allow the parent to use it.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to close popup and reload parent page, You should use this.

```
window.opener.location.href='/pageurl.html?id=1'
window.close();
```